# Centering left-aligned text

Tags: html, css

I want to center left-aligned text in the yellow box (txtbox).
It looks like that now:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/A1LaF0d.png]

and it want it to be looking like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/yHNjFqk.png]

HTML:

```
       <div class="content container small">
                    <div class="txtbox">
                        <header style="text-align:left;">
                            <h2>I AIN'T</h2>
                            <h2>AN ARTIST.<h2>
                            <h2>I'M A</h2>
                            <h2>BEAST!</h2>
                        </header>
                    </div>
                <footer>
                    <a href="#one" class="button style2 down">More</a>
                </footer>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container.small {
    /* width: (containers) * 0.75; */
    width: 900px;
}
.txtbox{
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:yellow;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Change `text-align:left` to `text-align:center` ?

Comment: i would recommend first thing setting `border` to all your elements, and checking their width. in order to center the text, the element has to be wider

Comment: I think [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/586Ez/) is what you want. `header` is a block element so by default takes 100% and hence `margin: 0 auto;` wouldn't have any visual effect. You need to assign a width to it.

Comment: What do you mean by left-aligned centered text? That sounds contradictory, like a round square. And the image seems to show just centered text. It is unclear what the vertical red line is meant to say. Please clarify by **editing the question**.

Answer (score 2):

```
.txtbox header h2{
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that I want to keep it in line like that: http://i.imgur.com/yHNjFqk.png

Comment: @BartoszJastrzębski But that's not centering, that's adding a big padding on the left.

Comment: @BartoszJastrzębski edited the answer. wumm is right, this is not centering.

Answer (score 1):

```
.txtbox header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr; 
    width: fit-content;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: left;
    align-items: center;
}
```

This will put your text in a box. Align the text to the left of the box and fitting the box for the text you have.
Then it will center the box.
This also works when you don't know the width or height.

And remove

```
style="text-align:left;"
```

out of the header.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the inline style in your

```
<header style="text-align:left;">
```

it overrides the stylesheet; leave just

```
<header>
```

Comment: @Farid Sure, it basically does, but as the OP just pointed out we all understood him wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
header h2 { position: relative; left : 30% /* percentage of yellow box */; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a little bit to figure out what "centered left-aligned" text mean.

If I understand you correctly, You want the text to be left-aligned on a vertical axis, but centered on the page.

If that is what you want than you can do that by centering your inner header tag like so: `width: 132px; margin: 0 auto;`

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/u4sj7/

Answer (score 0):

```
                <div class="txtbox">
                  <div class="centerblock">
                    <header style="text-align:left;">
                        <h2>I AIN'T</h2>
                        <h2>AN ARTIST.<h2>
                        <h2>I'M A</h2>
                        <h2>BEAST!</h2>
                    </header>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
.centerblock {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="content container small">
    <div class="txtbox">
        <header>
             <h2>I AIN'T</h2>
             <h2>AN ARTIST.</h2>
             <h2>I'M A</h2>
             <h2>BEAST!</h2>
        </header>
    </div>
    <footer> <a href="#one" class="button style2 down">More</a>

    </footer>
</div>
```

Add this to CSS:

```
.txtbox header {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```